# login control error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-membership, login-control

When I add the login control to the page, I got the following error. Could u help me ?

> "WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping
>   for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have jQuery in your project and have something like this in Global.asax to register jQuery properly:

```
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition {
            Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
            DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js",
            CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
        });
```

Replacing the version of jQuery with the version you are using. You can also disable this new feature in web.config by removing the following line:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
```

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735928/in-asp-net-web-application-visual-basic-the-requiredfieldvalidator-doest-work

**Edit:**

From the comments below, if the ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode is set to `WebForms` rather than removing it, you can change the value to `None` as shown below:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
```

Comment: I found that I needed to ADD the following line to web.config as per the answer from Bharath Kumar...
**<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="none" />**

Comment: @philwilks - the OP said this had worked for him.  Please don't downvote because another answer was more suited to YOUR problem, when my answer is suited to the question.

Comment: @DarrenDavies fair enough, sorry about that.

Comment: @DarrenDavies if you can edit your answer in some small way I think that will allow me to remove the downvote. Perhaps you could add that if this entry already exists, the value can be set to "none" instead?

Answer (score 7):

**WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).**

when you get this kind of error while your contacting login page then 
steps:

1.go to "web.config".

1. Find this code `<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms"/>`                                        in the web.config.
2. Change the value="WebForms" to value="none".
3. Now you open the login.aspx file it will open.

Answer (score 6):

As a side note: If you are using Visual Studio and encounter this problem when starting with an empty site, your config file may not have these lines. You then have to add the `<appSettings>` element and place the line inside of the tags. Example:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, in case someone else has this issue, I had to add the following

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

within the configuration tag, but outside of (before) the system.web tag. I'm using VS 2012 for Web (Express).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could install the Nuget package

> AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery